# После переноса проекта C# asp net core на другую машину перестали загружаться библиотеки jquery, bootstrap,

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp

Делал проект C# asp net core на одной машине, потом залил в Github, затем клонировал с Github на другую машину. Запускаю в среде разработке VS 2019, приложение запускается, но выдает ошибки о том, что не удалось загрузить JS библиотеки:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> datatables.min.css:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> jquery.min.js:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> datatables.min.js:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> jquery.min.js:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> bootstrap.min.css:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>
> localhost/:69 GET
> https://localhost:44381/lib/DataTables/datatables.min.css
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>
> localhost/:70 GET
> https://localhost:44381/lib/DataTables/datatables.min.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>
> localhost/:71 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:44381/'
> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
> 'http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Russian.json'. This
> request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

На предыдущей машине всё работало норм

При завершении программы пишет (2-е последние строки):

> Программа "[21044] iisexpress.exe: Трассировка программы" завершилась
> с кодом 0 (0x0).
> Программа "[21044] iisexpress.exe" завершилась с кодом -1 (0xffffffff).

Пробовал гуглить, но толкового решения не нашел

Обнаружил, что у меня не скопировался файл с настройками запуска:

```
launchSettings.json
```

Среда разработке его создала заново:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58424/",
      "sslPort": 44361
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "voteCollector": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Попытался его привести к виду, который у меня был на 1-ой машине, где все работало, тольrо порты оставил новые, те что сгенерировала VS:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58424/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
    "voteCollector": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Ошибки не ушли. Пробую запускать проект просто скопированный целиком с 1-ой машины - ошибок нет.

Перекопировал все файлы в ручную, при запуске проекта файл .sln и каталог obj в проект не добавился, без obj ошибок нет, если включаю каталог obj в проект при сборке выдает ошибки:

> Ошибка    CS2001  Не удалось найти исходный файл
> "E:\C#\voteCollector\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Razor\Views\Account\login.cshtml.g.cs".  voteCollector   E:\C#\voteCollector\CSC 1   Активные

Хотя этот файл в каталоге на самом деле есть.

Comment: Вебрут то скопировали?

Comment: @aepot, папка wwwroot с библиотеками есть

Comment: @aepot, вебрут это файл?

Comment: Это wwwroot....